# Как скачать произвольный текст в формате html, выведенный на страницу?

Tags: php, javascript

На страницу передается текст(создан в wysiwyg редакторе) в переменной $model->content.
С помощью download хочу сделать скачивание данного текста в файл.

$this->registerJs(<<

```
$('.btn-download').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    download(new Blob(["$model->content"]), "fileName");
});
```

})();
JS
)
?>

При таком вызове получаю ошибку "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", в инспекторе кода вижу что там проблема с кавычками(потому что в тексте есть кавычки тоже)

Если вызвать так:
download("$model->content", "$name");
То ошибка:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вообще передать туда правильно текст?

Answer (score 0):

```
download(new Blob(["<?php echo $model->content?>"]), "fileName");
```

Comment: подсвечивает ошибку в консоле
 download(new Blob(["<?php echo <p align="justify">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;;" и так далее

Comment: Эх. Файлы JS не обрабатываются интерпретатором PHP, поэтому в консоль вылетел не обработанный php код. Вы хотя бы называние файлов и их расположение привели

Comment: какие файлы?
На странице только текст и данный текст нужно экспортировать.

Comment: Покажите весь исходный текст